# Weird format for the process name

Tags: latex, pdflatex

When I compile the LaTex file to pdf file, I got something like

[image: Weird senstence]

And my LaTex code is

```
When only displaying the cards, the average CPU usage 
for \textit{com.google.android.wearable.app} is about 5\% and the average CPU 
usage for surface flinger process is about 1\%.
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very similar question has been asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59122/how-to-avoid-using-sloppy-document-wide-to-fix-overfull-hbox-problems). This could fix  your problem.

You could force hyphenation by using `\-`, e.g. `\textit{com\-.google.android.wearable.app}`, or force a linebreak with `\linebreak` or `\\`.

More [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34721/why-do-hyphenated-words-cause-margin-violations-and-how-can-i-prevent-it).